# Listing the properties of Object.prototype

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print  out the properties of `Object.prototype` but keep getting `undefined` as a result. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
for (var property in Object.prototype) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log(property);

    }
}
```

`undefined`

Comment: Because those properties are non-writable, non-enumerable, and non-configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meager's answer is correct, but i will explain how to do what you wanted here.

You need to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to get a list.

```
var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype);
for (var i=0; i<properties.length; i++) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(properties[i])) {
        console.log(properties[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not "getting undefined", your loop is simply executing 0 times, and your JavaScript console's REPL is showing you the value of the last statement is "undefined".

`Object.prototype` [has no enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).